# CSS hide all elements, except one with certain child

Tags: css

I have this element here:

```
#ihf-main-container .col-xs-6
```

I want to hide all the `.col-xs-6` inside `#ihf-main-container`, except the `.col-xs-6` element that has `.ihf-for-sale-price` inside of it....How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You cannot accomplish this using pure css.

Comment: It would be great if you attached your actual HTML and CSS to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Like Phiter says, there's no css selector for this case yet. A parent selector will be available in CSS4.

- For now, I would suggest to add an extra class to the .col-xs-6 element and hide them by that class.
- Don't show them at all by the use of the serverside script you're using (nicest way I think)
- Or use javascript (for the JS libary jQuery it can be something `$(".ihf-for-sale-price").parent().hide();` )

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand exactly but you could just name your last column as

```
  <....  class="col-xs-6  newName" > in html
```

And then in css you could do

```
  .col-xs-6{
    display = none;
    }
   .newName{
   display = block;
   }
```

Hope this works but I feel I could help you better if you could add some pseudo code with the question.